# Run mouseEntered function with a view controller

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

I am starting out with Swift and have a very basic OSX application that works. I have used storyboard to add a view and within that a webview.

However I can't seem to run a function when the mouse enters that view.

Here's my view controller. At the bottom you can see I have a function to set some window properties when the mouse enters the view.

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressIndicator: NSProgressIndicator!

    override func viewDidAppear() {
        super.viewDidAppear()

        let urlString = "http://google.com"

        self.webView.mainFrame.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!))
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    override func webView(sender: WebView!, didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame frame: WebFrame!) {
        self.progressIndicator.startAnimation(self)
    }

    override func webView(sender: WebView!, didFinishLoadForFrame frame: WebFrame!) {
        self.progressIndicator.stopAnimation(self)
    }

    override func mouseEntered(event: NSEvent) {
        self.view.window?.titleVisibility = .Hidden
        self.view.window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
        self.view.window?.styleMask |= NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To use NSResponder methods (like mouseEntered:, mouseDown:, mouseUp: etc.) in NSViewController you should initialize tracking area for this.

Check up "[Using Tracking-Area Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TrackingAreaObjects/TrackingAreaObjects.html)" Apple guide.